# how to make correct format json using javascript to use a service?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest, service

I'm calling a service, I have already the correct conection but I have a error, I think so the format json is incorrect.

ERROR: net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error).

I'm using Jquery Ajax

```
    var markers = '"identificacion":["1019035955"]';
    var markersConvertido = JSON.stringify(markers);
    var username = "Admisiones";
    var password = "admisiones";    

 $.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/AdministradorFotografiasJsonPS/fotos/consultar",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "
            + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },          
        crossDomain: true,  
        data: markersConvertido,
       success: function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            // alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Service using postman
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `JSON Object` using `{}`  and then to add new items to it you can use `jsonobject["keyname"]="somevalue"`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var markers = {}; //create obj
var markersss_array = []
markersss_array.push("1019035955");
//more datas push in array
markers["identificacion"] = markersss_array; //pass aray to json object
console.log(markers)
var markersConvertido = JSON.stringify(markers);
```